# Android ssl connection using HttpsURLConnection and verifying hostname using .pem files?

Tags: android, https

In `android` app I am developing I need to make connection to `https` server.

Client has provided me with 2 files `mycert.pem` and `mykey.pem`, which I think is `certificate` and `public keystrore` of server.

I need to make secure connection using `HttpsURLConnection` and `verify host name` of server to avoid man in middle attack. I have little understanding about making https connection and cryptography terms. Most of tutorial I came across uses HttpClient and they trust all host. Can someone point me in right direction how to use `.pem` files to make a `secure https` connection using `HttpsURLConnection` and `verify hostname`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to enable a self-signed certificate for SSL sockets on Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3265053/how-to-enable-a-self-signed-certificate-for-ssl-sockets-on-android)

Answer (score 0):

OK done by using following

```
httpsConn.setHostnameVerifier(org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);
```

I am using `BROWSER_COMPATIBLE_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER`, I hope it works well.