# Android XMPP using smack: No response from server

Tags: android, xmpp, smack

I'm trying to make an application which uses XMPP to send messages to a gmail account. I found a link which mentions the name of Google's XMPP server, but I dont think that I am able to make a connection.

**EDIT** I changed the name of the server and I believe it was able to establish a connection. But it says there are 0 entries for the Rosters. I am trying to login using a gmail account. The new exception I got:

```
07-05 14:02:05.099: W/System.err(13903): java.security.KeyStoreException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: KeyStore jks implementation not found
07-05 14:02:05.099: W/System.err(13903):    at java.security.KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.java:119)
07-05 14:02:05.099: W/System.err(13903):    at org.jivesoftware.smack.ServerTrustManager.<init>(ServerTrustManager.java:70)
07-05 14:02:05.099: W/System.err(13903):    at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.proceedTLSReceived(XMPPConnection.java:824)
07-05 14:02:05.099: W/System.err(13903):    at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketReader.parsePackets(PacketReader.java:267)
07-05 14:02:05.099: W/System.err(13903):    at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketReader.access$000(PacketReader.java:43)
07-05 14:02:05.099: W/System.err(13903):    at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketReader$1.run(PacketReader.java:70)
07-05 14:02:05.099: W/System.err(13903): Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: KeyStore jks implementation not found
07-05 14:02:05.099: W/System.err(13903):    at org.apache.harmony.security.fortress.Engine.notFound(Engine.java:177)
07-05 14:02:05.099: W/System.err(13903):    at org.apache.harmony.security.fortress.Engine.getInstance(Engine.java:151)
07-05 14:02:05.099: W/System.err(13903):    at java.security.KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.java:116)
07-05 14:02:05.099: W/System.err(13903):    ... 5 more
```

Here is the original exception :

```
07-05 13:30:23.444: W/System.err(12434):    at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketReader.parsePackets(PacketReader.java:306)
07-05 13:30:23.454: W/System.err(12434):    at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketReader.access$000(PacketReader.java:44)
07-05 13:30:23.454: W/System.err(12434):    at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketReader$1.run(PacketReader.java:76)
07-05 13:30:38.229: D/Smack(12434): Start Login
07-05 13:30:43.235: E/Smack(12434): Error: No response from the server.
07-05 13:30:43.235: W/System.err(12434): No response from the server.: 
07-05 13:30:43.235: W/System.err(12434):    at org.jivesoftware.smack.NonSASLAuthentication.authenticate(NonSASLAuthentication.java:58)
07-05 13:30:43.235: W/System.err(12434):    at org.jivesoftware.smack.SASLAuthentication.authenticate(SASLAuthentication.java:232)
07-05 13:30:43.245: W/System.err(12434):    at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.login(XMPPConnection.java:341)
07-05 13:30:43.245: W/System.err(12434):    at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.login(XMPPConnection.java:301)
07-05 13:30:43.255: W/System.err(12434):    at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.login(XMPPConnection.java:283)
07-05 13:30:43.255: W/System.err(12434):    at com.example.xmpp.MessageTask.doInBackground(MessageTask.java:33)
07-05 13:30:43.255: W/System.err(12434):    at com.example.xmpp.MessageTask.doInBackground(MessageTask.java:1)
07-05 13:30:43.265: W/System.err(12434):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
07-05 13:30:43.265: W/System.err(12434):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
07-05 13:30:43.275: W/System.err(12434):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
07-05 13:30:43.275: W/System.err(12434):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
07-05 13:30:43.275: W/System.err(12434):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
07-05 13:30:43.285: W/System.err(12434):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
07-05 13:30:43.285: W/System.err(12434):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Here is my code:

```
ConnectionConfiguration config = new ConnectionConfiguration("xmpp.l.google.com", 5222);
        XMPPConnection connection =  new XMPPConnection(config);
        try {
            Log.d("Smack", "Start Connect");
            connection.connect();
            Log.d("Smack", "Start Login");
            connection.login(user, pwd);
            Roster roster = connection.getRoster();
            //Get all rosters
            Collection<RosterEntry> entries = roster.getEntries();
            //loop through
            Log.d("Smack", "Start Rosters");
            for (RosterEntry entry : entries) {
            //example: get presence, type, mode, status
            Presence entryPresence = roster.getPresence(entry.getUser());
              String status = entryPresence.getStatus();
              Toast.makeText(context, status, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              Log.d("Smack", "Print rosters");
            }
            Log.d("Smack", "End Rosters");

        } catch (XMPPException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.e("Smack", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried testing it with other XMPP servers than Google's? Google is starting to switch from XMPP to a new protocol for its hangouts application.

**Try xmpp.l.google.com instead, and tell me if it works**

Comment: I tried it with that server and I got an exception which I have posted above. Was I just using the wrong google server? I am currently trying to login using a google account.

Comment: There is a project called Beem which also uses asmack for XMPP connection and it is open source. You could try it and see if it still works with Google talk. **http://beem-project.com/projects/beem/files**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Smack "No Response From Server". Not sure why am i getting this error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11712671/smack-no-response-from-server-not-sure-why-am-i-getting-this-error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try looking at those questions. It might be related

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11716952/984466

[Does android support .jks keystore type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9312193/does-android-support-jks-keystore-type)

[How to enable a self-signed certificate for SSL sockets on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3265053/how-to-enable-a-self-signed-certificate-for-ssl-sockets-on-android)

Comment: Awesome, the first link had the solution to my problem.

Comment: @Vannen i followed this way,its showing error in trust store path,throwing NPE in java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.io.File.fixSlashes(File.java:185)
at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:134)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:105)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.ServerTrustManager.<init>(ServerTrustManager.java:62)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.proceedTLSReceived(XMPPConnection.java:839)